# Magento 2 create plugin for my module

Tags: magento2, plugin

I have created plugin to add link for every product as below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin;

class ProductData
{


    protected $urlInterface;

    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
        ) {
        $this->urlInterface = $urlInterface;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function aroundGetProductDetailsHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
        )
    {
        $result = $proceed($product);

         return $result . '<a href="#">mydata</a>';

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Above is working fine added mydata link to every product. But it is not working on search page. Can anyone help me to add link to search page product using plugin

di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

     <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="my-block"
                type="Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\ProductData"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you post your `di.xml` file please ?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I have added di.xml code it is working fine but how can i achieve same function on search page.

Comment: @PrashantValanda I have facing same issue if you have got solution so please put here.

Comment: Add an additional entry for SearchList class in `di.xml`

Answer (score 0):

Basically the search page uses the same template as the product list **BUT it uses a virtual type block that uses the `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` class you're plugin.**

```
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="catalogLayer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

That's where the official documentation is confusing because in the [list of plugin limitations](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) it is said that:

> Plugins cannot be used with Virtual types

However, the following example is given:

```
<config>
    <type name="{ObservedType}">
        <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{PluginClassName}" sortOrder="1" disabled="true"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And it is said that:

> type name. A class, interface, or **virtual type**, which the plugin
>   observes.

Really confusing here, what I would try if I were you would still to try plugin the virtual type by updating your `di.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

     <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="my-block"
                type="Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\ProductData"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
     <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct">
        <plugin name="my-search-block"
                type="Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\ProductData"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: I have tried with your given solution it is not working. Having any other way?

Comment: @PrashantValanda I'm trying to find out the clarification about virtual types

Answer (score 0):

```
 <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="my-block"
            type="Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\ProductData"
            sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
<virtualType name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct" type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
   <plugin name="my-search-block"
            type="Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\ProductData"
            sortOrder="10"/>
</virtualType>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your di.xml. its displaying on catalog search page.

```
<type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\SearchResult\ListProduct">
    <plugin name="catalog-search-block" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ProductData" sortOrder="11"/>
</type>
```